# "SR" instead of "MZ"

Tags: windows, pe

I have pulled bunch of files from Virus Total based on hashes, one sample (`SHA256 == 3e6ee07c883a6a0e939300a18c61d639a0dea49521037fef09ae77b76f70f843`) was really weird.

Basically it is PE file (*.exe file to be more precise), however first two bytes in file are `SR` instead of `MZ`.

Have been looking online if it can be some *magic* that can be executed in Windows machines but no success. I guess it is some kind of corrupted file, however not sure, so asking if someone has any references to `SR` files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably it's just a measure to prevent scanning of the file by standard antiviruses. I suspect the malware either restores `MZ` before actually running the file, or uses a custom loader (a la RunPE) to map and execute it, and of course the custom loader can be coded to handle the `SR` signature in addition (or instead of) `MZ`.

Comment: Just had a look at that file, changing SR to MZ makes the file work (can be loaded and recognized by pe tools)

Comment: Make sense, however that file looks legit and custom loader and AV scanning prevention is weird for legit files.